# My progam on Game Maker Studio 2 is not showing currency signs (like £,$, etc.)

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

I am trying to make a shop in my game, and I want my text to say, "Object - £30" or something, but when I type in the sign, when I run the game, all it says is `Object - 30` even if I typed in  the sign. here is the code:

```
draw_self();

draw_text_transformed(x + -90, y + -20, string("Shelf - £ 60") + "", 2, 2, 0);

draw_set_colour($FF000000 & $ffffff);
var l4109CEE6_0=($FF000000 >> 24);
draw_set_alpha(l4109CEE6_0 / $ff);
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Your font of choice must contain the said glyph (you can check with FontForge)
2. You need to add a range for the glyph(s) in GameMaker:
   [image]

Comment: To be honest I don't know what you are talking, about. Could you tell me how to do those 2 things?

Comment: For the second, you open the font and click "Add" next to "Add new range", as per [documentation](https://manual.yoyogames.com/#t=The_Asset_Editors%2FFonts.htm). For the first, well, you download FontForge, you open your font in it, and you scroll down to the symbol to see if it has anything drawn in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using unicode?

\u00A3 for £ for example